# Anime involving a floating island with many moons

Tags: story-identification, anime

The anime is like this: There is a girl and she has friends (kids and mostly boys). Then her only memory is a floating island with many moons. Then they discovered that the girl is the princess of some sort of planet or whatever, and she was reincarnated, and when she was reincarnated, she has no memory of her previous life. Her only memory is that floating island with many moons. That is why she always paints it or draw it.

Comment: Floating islands, many moons, princess? Almost sounds like sky's of Arcadia

Answer (score 2):

## [Fantastic Children](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fantastic_Children)  (2004-2005)

From [Wikipedia's list of character's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Fantastic_Children_characters):

> Helga (ヘルガ, Heruga)
>
> A quiet and introverted young girl. She spends her time drawing pictures. She keeps to herself and always has a straight face and she worries about others around her. She and her friend, Chitto, attempt to escape from an orphanage in Chikao to search for a place Helga has envisioned in her mind. This place is often the subject of her drawings. 3rd Reincarnation of Tina.
>   Voiced by: Shiho Kawaragi (Japanese)

[image]